# Find Special Function from Series Form?

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series, laguerre-polynomials

I obtained this list of series (there are more but listed up to 5th order) and I suspect they are related to the [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials). Strictly speaking they are not $L_n^{\alpha}(x)$ but something close.

Is there a way to figure out the parameterization? It may be the derivatives or integrals of $L_n^{\alpha}(x)$. Any hints are welcome!

[image]

Comment: Some info might be available at *[this OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A121757)* which provides unsigned values of the coefficients of the numerator polynomials.

Comment: @epi163sqrt Thanks! I found [this](https://oeis.org/A132159) site before I posted my question simply by googling the series but did not understand how to use it. The mention to Laguerre polynomials is at the top

Comment: You're welcome. Meanwhile you also got a nice answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As epi163sqrt's link demonstrates, the polynomials are

$$P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \frac{(n - k+1)!}{n!}(-x)^k$$
Which simplifies to
$$P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n-k+1}{k!}(-x)^k$$

If we define $E_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$ to be the $n$-th order Taylor polynomial for $e^x$, then $$P_n(x) = (n+1)E_n(-x) + xE_{n-1}(-x)$$

Comment: Many thanks, this is it indeed! In the meantime I got to the same conclusion by other means. Maple could convert my formulas to the difference of two Laguerre polynomials, but i think that representation is more complicated than this here.

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos - Note that I just modified the post, I forgot about the $(-x)$ in my last formula.